# Registering achievements: Object Base Domain Not Allowed, even when domain IS allowed

Tags: facebook-opengraph, achievements

I have an Open Graph achievement at the following URL:

http://rinth.bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/Achievements_LOCAL/Achievement1.html

When I attempt to register it, I get a response of: status code 400:  OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#3502) Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement"

When I bring up the debug tool to have it validate the HTML:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frinth.bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com%2FAchievements_LOCAL%2FAchievement1.html

I get the following errors:

Object Base Domain Not Allowed: Object at URL 'http://rinth.bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/Achievements_LOCAL/Achievement1.html' of type 'game.achievement' is invalid because the domain 'rinth.bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '217132388329112'.

Missing Required Property: The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:title property is required, but not present.

I verified that this domain IS allowed by our application.  Just in case, I also tried the entire process using a different domain (which resulted in the exact same error).

The graph URL at the bottom of the debug tool prints the following:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears I was mistaken.  My App Domain changes were being silently discarded (see this question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7616965).

I added a Website URL pointing to my achievement host, and things appear to work now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you have to add "rinth.bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com" to the list of app domains in your application settings.

This security measure is there so that you can only access achievements from domains and applications that you specify.